# The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<TourClaimModel,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (List<TourClaimModel>)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am unable to understand why am not able to use save method in controller. I am using spring boot version 2.2.6. When is use this method it showing this error "The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<TourClaimModel,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (List)"

Here is my code,

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/tourClaim")
public String tourClaimApprovedByYuv(@RequestBody ArrayList<Integer> claimidList, Principal p) {
  String result = "";
  List<TourClaimModel> tour = tourClaimRepository.findByIdIn(claimidList);
  tourClaimRepository.save(tour);
  result = "Success";

  return result;
}
```

how can I resolve this?

Comment: If you read, the error itself is telling you where you have the error. The ```tourClaimRepository.save``` does not accept a list, but rather an object. The first argument is a ```TourClaimModel ```object and the second argument is an ```integer```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CrudRepository#save` is used for persisting one entity.
If you want to save many, you need to use [saveAll](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#saveAll-java.lang.Iterable-)

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/tourClaim")
public String tourClaimApprovedByYuv(@RequestBody ArrayList<Integer> claimidList, Principal p) {
  String result = "";
  List<TourClaimModel> tour = tourClaimRepository.findByIdIn(claimidList);
  tourClaimRepository.saveAll(tour);
  result = "Success";

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the list of `TourClaimModel` and save each one of them:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/tourClaim")
public String tourClaimApprovedByYuv(@RequestBody ArrayList<Integer> claimidList, Principal p) {
    String result = "";
    List<TourClaimModel> tours = tourClaimRepository.findByIdIn(claimidList);
    for (TourClaimModel tour : tours) {
      tourClaimRepository.save(tour);
    }
    result = "Success";

    return result;
}
```

However, I don't get what you are trying to achieve since you are saving the objects you just retrieved from the database without any change.